# PubNubSwift Capture Receive Message

Tags: swift, webrtc, pubnub

I'm working with PubNub. I have a standard WebRTC string being published with PubNub.

```
self.pubnub.publish(channel: self.channels[0], message: ["type": "offer", "sdp": sessionDesc.sdp]) { result in
```

Then the PubNub Listener listens to the Published signals on the Channel.

```
let listener = SubscriptionListener(queue: .main)
listener.didReceiveMessage = { message in
print("[Did Receive Message]: \(message)")
}
pubnub.add(listener)
pubnub.subscribe(to: channels, withPresence: true)
```

That works just fine, I get my SDP strings.

```
[Did Receive Message]: User 'pn-4D77E0B5-0145-ACAC-0366CB301ABC' sent '{"type":"offer","sdp":"v=0\r\no=- 4836309355638585269 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE audio video\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS ARDAMS\r\nm=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 102 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:tKqW\r\na=ice-pwd:KNDM86R+JqsLqupw3J288kmJ\r\na=ice-options:trickle renomination\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256.....
```

My problem is that from within 'message'. How do I capture the 'type' and 'sdp' strings???

```
listener.didReceiveMessage = { message in
print("[Did Receive Message]: \(message)")
var type = message["type"] as? String <---- this does not work.
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you sending the SDP as a string in the publish payload? If so, it is probably being escaped and you just need to unescape it and/or parse it. This should just be some Swift code and nothing PubNub specific. If you can parse the SDP string before publish and send it as Dictionary in Swift then it should deserialize as such on the subscribe side, too.